# Magento Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::initProductLayout()

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, magento

I'm working on a Magento site which has drop down menus to select different product variations.

However, it recently stopped working and now displays the following error along with Item Cannot Be Added to Cart when trying to add an item to the cart.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::initProductLayout()`

in

`/home4/wisestor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php` on line 67

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid given the information you provide this is a little like fishing in the dark without a lamp. Like, what Magento version are you using?

That said, since Magento 1.5 that method is implemented on the `catalog/product_view` helper, (as opposed to the `catalog/product` helper referenced in the error message you posted).

I believe you must have somehow hacked the core code, messing up the `Mage::helper()` factory method call in the *Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php* controller around line 67 to produce that error.

So instead of
`Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProductLayout($product, $this);` you want
`Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->initProductLayout($product, $this);`

Comment: That made the error go away, but I still can't add products to the cart. This is 1.5.1

Comment: Without further error messages or notices there is no way to help you. Check the developer mode is enabled, and look in the *var/log/system.log* and *var/log/exception.log* files. Also, **don't hack the core**.